# How to perform CPU throttling on mobile app performance testing

Tags: android, appium, performance-testing, cpu

I'm using android Google Pixel 4 device and I want to check mobile app performance on different CPU level.

Example:

**Use Case 1:** I want to calculate the my app launch time When the CPU usage on device is about to 30%.

**Use Case 2:** I want to calculate the my app launch time When the CPU usage on device is about to 50%.

**Use Case 3:** I want to calculate the my app launch time When the CPU usage on device is about to 80%.

It's kind of performance testing based on the CPU throttling.

Is there any tool which help me to simulate the CPU usage on my device so that I can test this use cases by manual?

Comment: I want to know when Samsung released Pixel 4 device.

Comment: Sorry typo. Pls ignore that